# How did the band get Marty out of the trunk of the car?

Tags: back-to-the-future

In the first Back to the Future film, Biff's cronies lock Marty in the boot of the band's car. They can't unlock the door, because Marty shouts

> "The keys are in the trunk!"
>
> Guitarist: "Say that again?"
>
> Marty: "I said, the keys are in here!"

So, how does he get out?

Comment: I don't get his question. Did you watch the movie?

Comment: @Kevin In Armageddon, the asteroid is 1 min away from a collision with earth. At the end of the movie, the earth is still intact. What happened to the asteroid??

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing, given the script quote and the images from the film itself. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [film script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/bttf4th.pdf) indicates that Marvin (the lead guitarist) used a screwdriver to jimmy the lock

> AT THE CADILLAC
>
> Marvin has his screwdriver in the lock. He gives it a hard jerk: the
>   trunk pops open, but he puts a big gash in his hand.
>
> **MARVIN:** *Damnit — I sliced my hand!*

[image]

Comment: Wow, the original script was... interesting...

Comment: @MikasaPinata - If you get a chance, have a read through the [earlier ones](http://www.overcast.com.br/overcastfiles/1DRAFT_BACK_TO_THE_FUTURE.html). They definitely improved with each drafting.

Comment: And now, we present you with: the importance of editing...

Answer (score 7):

The guitarist gets Marty out. He does this by using a screwdriver to pick the lock/force it open. This is what damages his hand- cutting himself on the screwdriver tip- preventing him from playing at the school dance, and causing Marty to step in.

Comment: I don't know what tool he uses to get out, though.

Comment: Flathead screw driver used to jimmy the lock. I don't think any cutting was involved, other than on his hand.

Comment: @Mazura thanks, edited.